# How can I compile an Emacs elisp extension (nXhtml)?

Tags: emacs, compilation, elisp

I'm new to Emacs and recently I installed nXhtml extension. How can I compile the extension?

Comment: `M-x byte-compile-file`, then enter the path to your `el`-file.

Comment: Any feedback? Did you finally succeed?

Comment: @Renauld I think I did.It exported an autostart.elc in my hxhtml folder... but just that, probably nxhtml.elc would be a better name... did it compiled everything else needed?

Comment: Ok,I did what you suggested and it seems it got better I hadn't seen you answer till now... sorry +1 and I mark it as correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumption: You have installed xhtml from the bazaar repository on launchpad  with `bzr branch lp:nxhtml`.

Now the answer: the README.txt file just told us

```
Note 3: You may optionally also byte compile nXhtml from the nXhtml
    menu (recommended).
```

Add `(load "~/.emacs.d/nxhtml/autostart.el")` to your `.emacs`, then `M-x eval-buffer`, activate the mode and as soon as you have a `nXhtml` entry in your menu, just browse `nXhtml → nXhtml Help and Setup → Byte compile nXhtml`.

Et voilà !

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you do not have to compile emacs extensions. You usually include something like

```
(load "YOUR-PATH-TO/nxhtml/autostart")
```

into your `.emacs`.

However, if you really want to *compile* your file, you can do this using the function `byte-compile-file` (via `M-x byte-compile-file`).

Comment: it actually works if you add the .elc in the end but does it compile the whole extension or just the specific file?will it make it run any faster?

Answer (score 1):

Speaking generally, for extensions like nxhtml which have many .el files and perhaps sub-directories, you would normally want to use `byte-recompile-directory`:

> byte-recompile-directory is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `bytecomp.el'.
>
> (byte-recompile-directory BYTECOMP-DIRECTORY &optional BYTECOMP-ARG
>   BYTECOMP-FORCE)
>
> Recompile every `.el' file in BYTECOMP-DIRECTORY that needs recompilation.
>   This happens when a`.elc' file exists but is older than the `.el' file.
>   Files in subdirectories of BYTECOMP-DIRECTORY are processed also.
>
> If the `.elc' file does not exist, normally this function *does not*
>   compile the corresponding`.el' file.  However, if the prefix argument
>   BYTECOMP-ARG is 0, that means do compile all those files.  A nonzero
>   BYTECOMP-ARG means ask the user, for each such `.el' file, whether to
>   compile it.  A nonzero BYTECOMP-ARG also means ask about each subdirectory
>   before scanning it.
>
> If the third argument BYTECOMP-FORCE is non-nil, recompile every `.el' file
>   that already has a`.elc' file.

- so to update any existing but out-of-date .elc files:
  <kbd>M-x</kbd> `byte-recompile-directory` <kbd>RET</kbd> (path to nxhtml) <kbd>RET</kbd>
- and to re/compile all .el files without asking for confirmation:
  <kbd>M-0</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd> `byte-recompile-directory` <kbd>RET</kbd> (path to nxhtml) <kbd>RET</kbd>

To read about prefix arguments:
<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(emacs) Arguments")` <kbd>RET</kbd>)

You may also like to look into using the likes of [ELPA](http://tromey.com/elpa/) (not applicable in this instance) or [el-get](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get) (which is) to install and maintain packages, as they take care of all the compilation and autoloads.